# New Azure Virtual Machine has no space left on /dev/sda1

Tags: azure, storage, conda

I created a new instance of an Azure Deep learning Virtual Machine, and already can't use it to install my Conda environment because the machine is already filled! How can I make some space, and why is this even happening?

```
/dev/sda1        49G   46G  3.4G  94% /
```

I understand that the Deep Learning / Data Science VMs come already with all esencial packages. But if there is no space left in the device, how are they supposed to be used? Do I need to purchase an extra storage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu Deep Learning Virtual Machine comes with two disks: the OS disk, mounted at /, and a data disk, mounted at /data. The OS disk is indeed mostly full, but the data disk has plenty of space. You can create a new conda environment on the data disk with the *-p* option. You can also free up some space on the OS disk with *conda clean -ltp*.

For the next release of the Ubuntu DLVM, we will be making more space available on the OS disk for you. That image will be released late this week or early next week.